# .NET Core 3.1 WebBrowserControl read html after navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, .net-core-3.1

I Seem to be unable to read HTML after a WPF web browser control has finished navigating to a page.

The reason I have to use a WebBrowser instead of a HttpClient, is because the required web page requires logging into first.

XAML:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbBrowse" Source="anywebpage" LoadCompleted="wbBrowse_LoadCompleted">
</WebBrowser>
```

Code:

```
  private void wbBrowse_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      var doc = wbBrowse.Document;
  }
```

I've tried casting Document to HtmlDocument but it crashes. It's a '{System.__ComObject}' object which means nothing to me.

Thanks

Comment: Where does it crash in your sample code...? What did you try?

Comment: If I try to cast the .Document to (HTMLDocument) or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` under Project->Add Reference->COM in Visual Studio and cast the value of `Document` to an `MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2`:

```
private void wbBrowse_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 doc = wbBrowse.Document as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2;
    ...
}
```

This does work in .NET Core 3.1.